# Javascript action changes after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a Javascript that triggers when the TrainingRequired checkbox is checked to show two submit buttons. When unchecked, one submit button is shown. The issue is when I check the checkbox and attempt to submit the form without data in one required field, an error message returns via postback. The checkbox remains checked and the two buttons no longer shows. How do I keep the two buttons visible after postback with an error message?

HTML markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="trainingRequired">
            Training Required?*</label>
    </td>
    <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("trainingRequired", Page.TrainingRequired, new { id = "chkImmediate" })
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="allowSelfTrainingBlock">
    <td>
        <label for="allowSelfTraining">
            Allow Self Training?</label>
    </td>
    <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("allowSelfTraining", Page.AllowSelfTraining)
    </td>
</tr>
```

RegularButton and RequiredButton blocks:

```
<div id="RegularButton">
<input name="btn" type="submit" id="notrequired" value="Save" />
<a href="@Page.ReturnUrl" id="notrequiredurl">Cancel</a>
</div>

<div id="RequiredButton">Create New Training Document?<br />
<input name="yesbtn" type ="submit" id="required" value="Yes" />
<input name="nobtn" type="submit" id="required2" value="No & Save" />
<a href="@Page.ReturnUrl" id="requiredurl">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Javascript on the same page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function prepareButtons() {
    document.getElementById("RequiredButton").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("RegularButton").style.display = "block";
}

//**********PostBack*************
function postBack(val) {
    $('#xtravar').val(val);
    $('form').submit();
}
$("#chkImmediate").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('allowSelfTrainingBlock').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("RequiredButton").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("RegularButton").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('allowSelfTrainingBlock').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("RequiredButton").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("RegularButton").style.display = "block";
    }
});
window.onload = function () {
    prepareButtons();
}
```

After postback with an error message, I can get the two buttons showing if I uncheck and check the TrainingRequired checkbox. But I really want the two buttons to show after the postback with an error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since page would be redrawn after a postback, window.onload would be invoked again. Therefore, you would need to set a condition to check if an error occured. Since your using MVC, you may create a ViewBag prop in the controller and set it if an error occured. Something like the following.

In controller,

```
public ActionResult Validate()
{
  if(Error)
  ViewBag.isError = true;
  return View();
}
```

In Js,

```
window.onload = function () {
    var error = '@ ViewBag.isError';
    if(error != 'true')
     prepareButtons();
}
```